# Inserting numeric data with non zero scale with table-valued parameter

Tags: java, sql-server-2016, table-valued-parameters

I am using table-valued parameters to insert large amounts of data into various tables. When those tables have numeric columns with scale and in a single data table there are rows that have varying numbers of scale I get the following error:

The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC) protocol stream is incorrect. Table-valued parameter 3 (""), row 0, column 0: Data type 0x6C has an invalid precision or scale

An example of when this happens.

- A table being inserted into and the associated tvp have a numeric(6,3) column
- There are 2 rows in the datatable being inserted

  - One has a value of 1.2 for the numeric column
  - The other has a value of 1.23 for the numeric column

If the second row in that example has a value of 1.3 for the numeric column there is no error. This is in Java using the jdbc42.jar from the Microsoft JDBC Driver 6.0 for SQL Server with a SQL Server 2016 database.

Answer (score 0):

After setting up an integration test and spending an hour or so trying different things I discovered the cause of this was that the values were being inserted as strings to the data table and having the value for a column being zero with multiple trailing zeroes causes this error.

"0" is okay, "0.0" is okay. "0.00" is not. Inserting into the row as numbers fixes it, 0.00 is okay.